# Getting LockAcquisitionException when making multiple requests simultaneously

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, load-testing

I'm working on a project when we create a unique ids for each product type in a warehouse. For doing that, I'm creating a stored procedure which would incrementally generate a new number every time. Here is the repository layer and the procedure

Procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_id(dataname text) RETURNS bigint AS $$
DECLARE
    data_value bigint;
BEGIN
   
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    BEGIN
            UPDATE identifier
            SET latest_id = latest_id + 1
            WHERE identifier_type = dataname
            RETURNING latest_id INTO data_value;
    END;
    -- Return the bigint value
    RETURN data_value;
END;
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ProductIdentifierRepository extends JpaRepository<Identifier, Integer> {

  @Procedure(value = "create_id")
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
  public Long updateId(@Param("dataname") String type);
}
```

While the code is working as expected for a few parallel api calls, it starts breaking when I make about 100 API calls in 30 seconds, and I get this exception :

```
Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [create_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException
```

Please help

Comment: Why this construction... That is what sequences are meant for, if you a really want this you would need to use SERIALIZABLE isolation so that only 1 will update that record.